# SQL table join display more fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm learning SQL and need a little advice. This currently displays what i need it to, however i also want to echo all the other fields that don't have a match between tw.model_id and model.id. Also how would i create a list if there's multiple customer_name any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tw
INNER JOIN model
ON model.id=tw.model_id
WHERE tw.completed = 1 AND tw.stock = 0
ORDER BY model.id"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<table cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='10px' align='center' width='100%'><tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<td width='7%' style='border:1px solid grey;'> " . $row["model_name"] . "<br />" . $row["quantity"] . "<br />";

    echo $row["customer_name"] . "<br /></td>";

}

 echo "</tr></table>";
```

It needs to be displayed like this:

```
|Model1     |Model2  |Model3
|10         |4       |6
|Joe Bloggs |        |Jane Doe
```

Currently it does not display Model2 column as it doesn't have a match between model ids and no customer name.

**table layout**

*Model*

```
id
model_name
quantity
```

*tw*

```
id
model_name
customer_name
model_id
```

model_name matches both tables
model.id matches tw.model_id

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: I have added the table layout and the expected result is the model1, model2, model3 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an outer join. Inner joins must have matches.

This might help:

https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM model
LEFT OUTER JOIN tw
ON model.model_name=tw.model_name
ORDER BY model.id

Left outer join worked. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM tw
OUTER JOIN model
ON model.id=tw.model_id
WHERE tw.completed = 1 AND tw.stock = 0
ORDER BY model.id
```

Outer join will do exactly what you need, i.e. " i also want to echo all the other fields that don't have a match between tw.model_id and model.id".